# pycharm and postgres: ERROR: Unsupported startup parameter: extra_float_digits

Tags: postgresql, pycharm

Having issue to connect to PostgreSQL 9.0 database from PyCharm. I already tried adding older jdbc driver manually but still getting the same error: "ERROR: Unsupported startup parameter: extra_float_digits".

Answer (score 24):

The "fix" is to add this to the `config.ini` under the `[pgbouncer]` section:

```
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
```

Details here: https://github.com/Athou/commafeed/issues/559

Answer (score 13):

I had this error using the PostgreSQL JDBC driver connecting to PgBouncer. The fix was to add the following to `pgbouncer.ini` (which was already in the file but commented out):

```
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
```

(similar to the previous answer but different config file)

Comment: Thank you!! this fixed my issue. Anyone trying to connect to Azure managed pgbouncer service, Go to server parameters in your database and search for pgbouncer.ignore_startup_parameters and input value 'pgbouncer.ignore_startup_parameters' and save.